# Can you apply the Vampiric Touch and Shocking Grasp damage together in one attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, actions

Can you apply *[vampiric touch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vampiric-touch)* and *[shocking grasp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shocking-grasp)* damage together in one attack?

*Vampiric touch* has concentrated duration of 1 minute and requires melee spell attack to deliver.

*Shocking grasp* requires a melee spell attack.

Can you deliver both effects at the same time with the same attack roll?

Comment: Is there a reason you think this *can* be done?

Comment: The "so does Shocking Grasp" is ambiguous - while we can easily look for the spell description, the way you wrote it is not clear if you are referring to both the concentration and requiring a MSA or just the MSA (the latter is the correct one for the spell).

Answer (score 15):

## Generally, no.

Both require an action. For [*shocking grasp*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shocking-grasp) to deal damage, you need to cast it using the Cast a Spell action. Its casting time is 1 Action.

The description of [*vampiric touch*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vampiric-touch) states:

> Until the spell ends, you can make the attack again on each of your turns **as an action**.

You only have one action, thus only one of them can be cast per turn. You might be confused thinking that *vampiric touch* replaces your melee attack or that when you attack its effect would activate - but that's not the case. You have to use your action to specifically attack with *vampiric touch*.

One exception would be using [Action Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#ActionSurge) as a multiclass Fighter/Wizard and casting both spells using two separate actions. That's probably not what you intended, though, since you ask **on the same attack roll** as well (and that would be impossible since these are two different actions making different attacks).